# Select by Date or Sort by date on GoogleNewsSource R

Tags: r, google-api, text-mining, tm, google-news

I am using the R package `tm.plugin.webmining`. Using the function `GoogleNewsSource()` I would like to query the news sorted by date and also from a specific date. Is there any paremeter to query the news of a specific date?

```
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.webmining)

searchTerm <- "Data Mining" 
corpusGoog <- WebCorpus(GoogleNewsSource(params=list(hl="en", q=searchTerm, 
                                         ie="utf-8", num=10, output="rss"  )))
headers <- meta(corpusGoog,tag="datetimestamp")
```

Comment: The GoogleNewsSource is giving back 'news'. I want to select the news by date and also that the given results are sorted by date. I am confused about how to do this when checking in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a data frame-like structure, this is how you'd go about creating it (note: not all fields are extracted from the corpus):

```
library(dplyr)

make_row <- function(elem) {
  data.frame(timestamp=elem[[2]]$datetimestamp,
             heading=elem[[2]]$heading,
             description=elem[[2]]$description,
             content=elem$content, 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

dat <- bind_rows(lapply(corpusGoog, make_row))
str(dat)

## Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ timestamp  : POSIXct, format: "2015-02-03 13:08:16" "2015-01-11 23:37:45" ...
##  $ heading    : chr  "A guide to data mining with Hadoop - Information Age" "Barack Obama to seek limits on student data mining - Politico" "Is data mining riddled with risk or a natural hazard of the internet? - INTHEBLACK" "Why an obscure British data-mining company is worth $3 billion - Quartz" ...
##  $ description: chr  "Information AgeA guide to data mining with HadoopInformation AgeWith the advent of the Internet of Things and the transition fr"| __truncated__ "PoliticoBarack Obama to seek limits on student data miningPoliticoPresident Barack Obama on Monday is expected to call for toug"| __truncated__ "INTHEBLACKIs data mining riddled with risk or a natural hazard of the internet?INTHEBLACKData mining is now viewed as a serious"| __truncated__ "QuartzWhy an obscure British data-mining company is worth $3 billionQuartzTesco, the troubled British retail group, is starting"| __truncated__ ...
##  $ content    : chr  "A guide to data mining with Hadoop\nHow businesses can realise and capitalise on the opportunities that Hadoop offers\nPosted b"| __truncated__ "By Stephanie Simon\n1/11/15 6:32 PM EST\nPresident Barack Obama on Monday is expected to call for tough legislation to protect "| __truncated__ "By Adam                             Courtenay\nData mining is now viewed as a serious security threat, but with all the hype, s"| __truncated__ "How We Buy\nJanuary 12, 2015\nTesco, the troubled British retail group, is starting over. After an accounting scandal , a serie"| __truncated__ ...
```

Then, you can do anything you want. For example:

```
dat %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  select(heading) %>%
  head

## Source: local data frame [6 x 1]
## 
##                                                                                      heading
## 1 The potential of fighting corruption through data mining - Transparency International (pre
## 2                              Barack Obama to seek limits on student data mining - Politico
## 3                    Why an obscure British data-mining company is worth $3 billion - Quartz
## 4              Parks and Rec Recap: Treat Yo Self to Some Data Mining - Indianapolis Monthly
## 5    Fraud and data mining in Vancouverâ\u0080¦just Outside the Lines - Vancouver Sun (blog)
## 6     'Parks and Rec' Data-Mining Episode Was Eerily True To Life - MediaPost Communications
```

If you want/need something else, you need to be clearer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at google query string and noticed they pass startdate and enddate tag in the query if you click dates on right hand side of the page.

You can use the same tag name and yout results will be confined within start and end date.

```
GoogleFinanceSource(query, params = list(hl = "en", q = query, ie = "utf-8",
               start = 0, num = 25, output = "rss", 
               startdate='2015-10-26', enddate = '2015-10-28'))
```